# Symbolic or numerical solution to sum-of-quadratic matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have an equation of the following form, where I would like to solve for square but not necessarily symmetric $d \times d$ matrix $X$:

$$
-N X^{-1} + \sum^N_{n=1} B^{(n)} X C^{(n)} = 0,
$$

where $n$ is an index over a sequence of $N$ different matrices, where each matrix $B^{(n)}$ and each matrix $C^{(n)}$ is $d \times d$ symmetric positive definite.

By multiplying by $X$, we obtain the following:

$$
\sum^N_{n=1} B^{(n)} X C^{(n)} X = N I_d.
$$

<s>If we had just one term (ie $N=1$), this would have the easy solution $X = B^{-1}  C^{-1}$. Is there a way to solve this for $N>1$?</s> How would one solve this for $N=1$, where $X C X = N B^{-1}$? And can this be extended to $N>1$?

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\sum_{n=1}^N B^{(n)} X C^{(n)} X = N I_d$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael - thanks for pointing this out! I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are unlikely to get a closed-form solution any easier than just treating this as a set of $d^2$ quadratic equations in $d^2$ variables.  I tried a random example with $N=3$ and $d=3$, solving the resulting set of equations using a Groebner basis.  The first element of the Groebner basis was an irreducible even polynomial of degree $80$ in $x_{3,3}$.

As for numerical solutions, I would not expect the standard numeric solvers for nonlinear systems to have any difficulties. In my example, Maple's `fsolve` found a solution in $0.016$ seconds of cpu time on my computer.